# Linq Sum inline

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to do something linke this?

Entity (with 3 Properties)
---> int A
---> int B
---> int C

```
from record in dbset
select new Entity  
{  
    A = record.A  
    B = record.B 
    C = A * B  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [object initialization syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx), you can only assign properties to field available at construction time.  So, you have two options if you want `C` to be computed off of `A` and `B`.  You can read those properties off of `record`:

```
from record in dbset
select new Entity  
{  
    A = record.A  
    B = record.B 
    C = record.A * record.B  
}
```

More complicated situations might make it untenable to repeat the definitions of `A` and `B` in this way.  For example, repeating a long definition for how those properties are computed might be computationally expensive.  It is also harder to read when similar code is repeated.  In those cases you might want to have an intermediary select class that gathers relevant information before the final select:

```
from record in dbset
select new { A = someComplicatedFunction(record.A), B = someComplicatedFunction(record.B) } into info
select new Entity { A = info.A, B = info.B, C = info.A * info.B }
```

Of course, if `C` is always computed off of `A` and `B`, then you could make a getter property, as suggested by @vc74

Answer (score 4):

In this specific example, use

```
from record in dbset
select new Entity  
{  
    A = record.A  
    B = record.B 
    C = record.A * record.B  
}
```